# Given a User & Authentications model - How to return all Users w/o a Authentication.provider = "facebook"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models:

```
User (id)
Authentication (id, provider,..)
```

How can I get all users that Do not have a authentication.provider eq to "facebook"?

Thanks

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user    
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authentications
```

Comment: give us the relation between authentication and user (how it is defined -> user has_one authentication or what? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD. Please, refer to [Octopus-Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608444/519295) for a better solution.**

I guess, it would look something like this:

```
User.joins(:authentications).where("authentications.provider != 'facebook'")
```

Comment: How about if user x has no entry in authentications? Or a user has several auths with FB among them? There is also the issue of duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN authentications ON authentications.user_id = users.id AND authentications.provider = 'facebook'").where("authentications.user_id IS NULL")
```

Let me explain it  a little bit => the `authentications.user_id IS NULL` will give you all the users that `don't` have a corresponding authentication from facebook

Comment: Thanks but that returns [] when it should have sent back data?

Comment: OP should use/accept this solution! bassneck's simplistic yet familiar solution is wrong on several levels. Working with a DB needs deep sql knowledge. @Lichtamberg learn more sql.

Comment: It's been a long time since this questions was posted. I can actually see how this solution is better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.select("DISTINCT users.*").joins("LEFT JOIN authentications ON authentications.user_id = users.id").where("authentications.provider != 'facebook'")
```

You should use LEFT JOIN here because with it, the query will return also users who don't have any authentications (i.e. users who don't have facebook authentications are also the users who don't have any authentications)